# Designer view is not load in windows phone application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

I installed visual studio 2012 ultimate and also windows phone sdk 8.0 in my windows 8 pro 64 bit with hyper-v enabled. But in visual studio screen designer view doesn't load. If I reload it then also does not load. It gives me exception which is as below:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
```

Comment: I am not sure... But maybe you need Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone. You can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone), or if you have Dreamspark, it's free. I have VS Pro 2012 and I can't program for WP, but maybe it's an installation problem...

Comment: If you haven't already installed the latest service pack and updates for VS2012, do so. The designer experience becomes significantly better with the latest updates. I use VS2012 Ultimate and the designer with no problems. You can, of course, still get errors like this if you have a DataContext or bindings that are causing problems for the designer.

Comment: I just solve this issue by uninstall vs2012 ultimate and again install it.and issue is solve.